# Kendo Mvc Grid clienttemplate

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I am using a Kendo MVC Grid and i want to have a dropdownlist in one of the cells.
here is my code:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<RMS.Admin.ViewModel>()
  .Name("ResourceGrid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(c => c.ResourceName);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Descritption);
      columns.Bound(c => c.ResourceType).ClientTemplate("#=ResourceType#");
      columns.Bound(c => c.Approved);
      columns.Bound(c => c.IsEnabled);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Data).Width(220);
      columns.Command(command =>
      {
          command.Edit();
          command.Destroy();
      }).Width(172).Title("Edit/Delete");
  })
  .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
  .Scrollable()
  .Sortable()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:800px" })
  .Pageable(pageable => pageable
      .Refresh(true)
      .PageSizes(true)
      .ButtonCount(5))
      .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Model(model =>
      {
          model.Id(s => s.ResourceId);
          model.Field(p => p.ResourceType).DefaultValue(ViewData["defResourceType"] as RMS.Admin.ViewModel.ResourceTypeId);
      })
                .Create(update => update.Action("CreateResource", "Home", new { resourceTypeId = "#=ResourceType.Id#" }))
                .Read(read => read.Action("ReadResource", "Home"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateResource", "Home"))
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("RemoveResource", "Home"))

    )
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
  )
```

The problem is that i don't know what clienttemplate is so i don't know what to do with it. 
If bound resourcetype with a clienttemplate i can't add new records to the grid, i get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: ResourceType is not defined

If i remove clienttemplate i can add a record but when i try to save it it says it can't find the id of ResourceType.

Comment: Try this. [link](http://cyanbyfuchsia.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/how-to-kendo-ui-grid-for-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 1):

basically if you want to use a dropdownlist within a kendo ui grid you have to define an editor template which includes a kendo dropdownlist widget. this means you have to declare the respective cell with the attribute .EditorTemplateName() like this:

```
.Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(c => c.ResourceName);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Descritption);
      columns.Bound(c => c.ResourceType).EditorTemplateName("TemplateName");
      columns.Bound(c => c.Approved);
      columns.Bound(c => c.IsEnabled);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Data).Width(220);
      columns.Command(command =>
      {
          command.Edit();
          command.Destroy();
      }).Width(172).Title("Edit/Delete");
  })
```

the editortemplate has to be stored within folder: Shared/EditorTemplates/TemplateName.cshtml

TemplateName.cshtml should look like this:

```
@model ModelName

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.OptionLabel("please select a value")    
.Name("ResourceType") <-- the name needs to be equal to the grid cell name
    .DataSource(source=>
        {
        source.Read( read =>
            {
                read.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");

            })
            .ServerFiltering(true);
        })
    .DataTextField("Name") <-- displays the text of the object
    .DataValueField("ID") <-- stores the id of the object
    )
```

hope this will lead you into the right direction.
cheers,